# What is the expression of the vector orthogonal to all linearly independent vectors but one?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n$ **linearly independent** vectors, $v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, .......v_{n}$.
How to find construct a vector that is **orthogonal** to $v_{2}, v_{3}, ....., v_{n}$ (all $v$ but not $v_{1}$) and what's the general expression of it?

Is brute force of solving $n-1$ equations the only way to find it, (or $A^{T}x = 0$, where the columns of $A$ are $v_{2}....v_{n}$)? If so, can this give me a neat expression of such vector in terms of $v_{i}$?

In addition, can Gram Schmitt process be a way to do this? Will Gram Schmitt process give me a neat expression of such vector in terms of $v_{i}$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt will indeed do it, as long as you order the vectors $\{v_2,\dots,v_n,v_1\}$ before beginning; the last vector output will be orthogonal to each of $\{v_2,\dots,v_n\}$. You can also take the determinant of the matrix whose top row consists of the symbols $\bf e_1,\dots,e_n$ and whose other rows are the vectors $v_2,\dots,v_n$.

Comment: @Greg Martin but isn't that last output orthogonal to the orthonormal bases {e2,....,en} created in previous steps only? Why is it also orthogonal to {v2,…,vn}?

Comment: Because the subspace spanned by $\{e_2,\dots,e_n\}$ is the same as the subspace spanned by $\{v_2,\dots,v_n\}$. That's the beauty of Gram-Schmidt!

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the Gram-matrix of $v_2,\dots,v_n$, that is $g_{ij}=\langle v_i,v_j\rangle$ and let $\tilde v$ the vector with $\tilde v_k=\langle v_1,v_k\rangle$. Then $G^{-1}\tilde v$ is the coordinate vector of the orthogonal projection of $v_1$ on the span of $v_2,\dots,v_n$. Hence $v_1-G^{-1}\tilde v$ is the desired vector.